# How to autoscroll to Top in Angular 2 on changing of link?

Tags: angular

After crossing the routerLink to another page, the page is save it position on X-axis if X is the top-bottom position.

I.e. when switching between tabs, the page is not displayed at the top.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible for you share sample code or plunker?

Comment: If you're on the same page (inner router outlet for ex) what you're looking for is scrollTo, just google angular2 scrollTo, here's the first one I found, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll